# Efficient way of finding the 5 largest numbers in an array at any given interval

Tags: javascript, arrays, hashtable

I am trying to find the five largest numbers at set intervals, while also Removing those values from the array. I need to grab the top candidates in their respective range. That range can change and the number that I need to query can also change. Is there an efficient and preferably elegant solution to this? By elegance, I mean an algorithmic (preferably hashed) approach that removes inefficient sorting or actions that do not contribute to performance on sparse and large arrays.

```js
var arr = [101, 88, 267, 175, 154, 39, 74, 217, 31, 105, 235, 31, 14, 49, 226, 195, 134, 207, 222, 281,
  262, 112, 133, 115, 0, 53, 128, 103, 88, 145, 238, 13, 204, 199, 100, 247, 292, 157, 141, 286,
  72, 160, 85, 61, 57, 54, 263, 50, 125, 179, 243, 281, 39, 76, 151, 79, 1, 238, 200, 249, 35, 82,
  204, 174, 293, 216, 84, 209, 170, 236, 3, 247, 25, 162, 25, 57, 49, 215, 8, 167, 180, 268,
  204, 257, 134, 151, 191, 81, 77, 106, 85, 128, 52, 136, 46, 185, 229, 116, 145, 253, 258, 222,
  269, 225, 101, 175, 265, 77, 32, 8, 72, 54, 111, 264, 292, 161, 91, 215, 139, 245, 73, 127, 297,
  73, 258, 183, 232, 55, 199, 175, 31, 24, 21, 155, 231, 95, 40, 223, 222, 86, 115, 210, 134, 229,
  211, 54, 294, 153, 52, 165, 168, 125,186, 185, 289, 188, 248, 61, 136, 15, 19, 92, 200, 80, 208,
  195, 241, 85, 288, 279, 119, 247, 208, 11, 80, 111, 29, 292, 222, 289, 70, 11, 209, 25, 267, 233,
  16, 289, 154, 141, 174, 30, 156, 40, 266, 139, 116, 241, 1, 101, 109, 61, 220, 265, 45, 178, 166,
  102, 181, 193, 202, 133, 200, 266, 114, 222, 231, 89, 190, 29, 20, 64, 233, 261,213, 40, 161, 167,
  100, 121, 288, 268, 50, 264, 78, 105, 21, 33, 79, 114, 5, 134, 56, 259, 124, 44, 134, 133, 74, 176,
  65, 68, 34, 56, 2, 287, 63, 167, 299, 59, 290, 241, 104, 75, 76, 116, 225, 297, 208, 136, 265, 290,
  170, 267, 10, 176, 141, 217, 195, 4, 173, 32, 150, 271, 238, 171, 195, 16, 282, 77, 62, 39, 44, 248,
  270, 222, 295, 122, 190, 230];
function maxAtIntervals (intervalLength, select, xs) {
    const comparator = (a, b, _) => a - b;
    const temp = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < xs.length; i += intervalLength) {
        const interval = xs.slice(i, i + intervalLength);
        temp.push(interval.sort(comparator).slice(-select));
    }

    return temp;
}
console.log(maxAtIntervals(20, 5, arr));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Okay, here's some FP tips for you!  When you use map, filter, reduce, they are in themselves creating an implicit (and invisible to the coder) for-loop.  So if you use one of these functions inside a for-loop, you are multiplicatively increasing the effort required (from n to n^2 for example).  Try watching some videos on map, filter, and reduce in javascript and I think the whole operation will become much clearer.

Comment: You'd better sort your array in ascending order then select 5 last items from your sorted array since they are 5 biggest numbers,  you'll gain performance boost from this tip I think

Comment: @ MeteorZero, I can Sort but not the whole array. I can sort on the intervals.

Comment: @Arrow You can solve it in linear time O(n) where n is the length of the array by using the [median of medians quickselect algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_of_medians) - but in practice, if your intervals or the number of maxima to 'grab' are small, I'd go with a simpler solution which will run faster for smaller arrays. So if performance is a concern, you should give us some idea about the expected values for 'interval' and 'grab'.

Comment: @le_m thanks! I never thought to look at median of medians quickselect.

Comment: @le_m Do your arrays have to be sorted before you can implement median of Means?

Comment: @Arrow No. The median of medians quickselect is based on quicksort - where the pivot element (separating the smaller from the bigger values) is the median element of your array interval. The algorithm is faster than quicksort however, because it doesn't really sort the array, just partitions it in larger and smaller elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have read @le_m's comment however finding the `k` largest / smallest items or the `k`th largest / smallest item is a complicated task in O(n). It's best implemented in sorting and taking the necessary ones from the beginning of the array.

Accordingly you may do as follows;

```js
function segmentAndTakeMax(ar,sl,mc) { // array , segment length, max count
  var tempar = Array.from({length: sl});
  return Array.from({length: Math.ceil(ar.length/sl)})
              .map((_,i) => tempar.map((_,j) => arr[i*sl+j])
                                  .sort((a,b) => b-a)
                                  .slice(0,Math.min(arr.length-i*sl,mc)));
}

var arr = Array.from(new Array(203), _ => ~~(Math.random()*100));
console.log(arr);
console.log(segmentAndTakeMax(arr,20,5));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Ok as per OP's performance concerns on V8 i have repharsed the code to use `.reduce()` which is much faster than `.map()` in V8. Here is the modified code.

```js
function segmentAndTakeMax(arr, n, m) {
  var li = arr.length-1;  // last index
  return arr.reduce((r,e,i,a) => i%n ? (r[r.length-1].push(e),                                                    // if i%n != 0 then do these -> push e to last sub array
                                        i == li && (r[r.length-1] = r[r.length-1].sort((a,b) => b-a).slice(0,m)), // short circuit for if i == last index then sort and slice the last sub array
                                        r)                                                                        // return r
                                     : (i && (r[r.length-1] = r[r.length-1].sort((a,b) => b-a).slice(0,m)),       // if i%n == 0 then do these -> short circuit for if i != 0 then sort and slice the last sub array
                                        r.push([e]),                                                              // push [e] (a new sub array) to r 
                                        r), []);                                                                  // return r
}

var arr = Array.from(new Array(203), _ => ~~(Math.random()*100));
console.log(arr);
console.log(segmentAndTakeMax(arr,20,5));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: I agree with the O(n) algorithm being probably slower due to large constant overhead for 'usual' inputs. However, @Arrow also asked for "Removing those values from the array" - so you could directly mutate `ar` instead of `tempar` if I understand your implementation correctly

Comment: @le_m `tempar` is a temporary array in the length of given segment size to map onto the corresponding input array values. So the result will be an array with subarrays each in length of the given segment size. Then while constructing the sub arrays, i also sort and then take the first `mc` many items.

Comment: nice, but I am not noticing a performance increase compared to what I have. Also, you are not removing the values.  However, your code is more concise than mine. I will select your answer if you no one answers in the next 3 days.

Comment: @Arrow JS is basically an imperative language with only some order of functionality in it's core like functions being passed around and returned. Other than this the functional tools like `map`, `reduce`, `filter` etc etc are all implementations over imperative code which yield a certain amount of performance loss. But their abstraction make the code very readable and most of the time the performance loss is negligible.

Comment: I don't know if it is negligible, These are some of the results I got my computer. for 60,000 randomly generated numbers

 randomly  between 1-100 on 
intervals of 1000 and on selections of 100 
interval 1000 selection 100
I got 17.947ms to 52.82ms.
intervals 20 selection 5
I got 15.22 to 50.487

 randomly  between 1-900 on 
intervals of 1000 and on selections of 100 
interval 1000 selection 100
I got 24.46ms to 53.203ms.
intervals 20 selection 5
I got 20.78 to 52.599

Comment: @Arrow Interesting... When i check the functional solution for 60000 items array with 0-99 randoms on intervals 1000 and selections 100 i get 9ms and your code gives like 25ms. This is on Firefox. Have you checked to correct `if (arrayLength > 200)` to `if (arrayLength > 60000)` on your lines 17 and 51? You can have a look at [mine here](https://repl.it/IJx8) and [your's here](https://repl.it/IJx8/1) for a comparison. Please let me know if there is something wrong with my interpretation.

Comment: Make sure you are doing them side by side because they are randomly generated numbers distributions affect performance. Also, you added a concat method to my operation, it is not necessary. [link](https://repl.it/IJx8/2) – Arrow 6 mins ago

Comment: @Arrow OK sorry i had added `concat` just to strip out the outermost array object. I guess in this case it can just be done by doing `result[0]`. But anyways.. as per your link it now seems on Firefox the functional code is around 10-15% slower while with a Webkit browser (I can only test your link with Epiphany on this machine) the functional is still slightly (~ 5%) faster. I can not check with Chrome until tomorrow. I guess the difference might be considered insignificant. What browser are you using..?

Comment: @Arrow.. OK as you have mentioned in V8 the initial code is considerably slower. This is particularly because of the `.map()` implementation of the V8 being much slower compared to FF's. Now i have rephrased the code to use `.reduce()` which seems to me better both in Chrome and FF. Please check it up [here](https://repl.it/IJx8/4)